Find max of row cumulative sum of adjacent columns by group in R
I have this data frame. What I want to find is the maximum of row cumulative sums for each group given that they are adjacent and have values =1. For example, Group 1 has Year 1,2,3,4 adjacent and values add up =4, and year6 =1 so the max value is 4 for group 1 and so on. Below is an example of data frame and the desired result. Thank you

df <- data.frame(group = c(1:6),
             Year1 = c('1','0','0','0','0','0'),
             Year2 = c('1','1','1','0','1','1'),
             Year3 = c('1','1','0','0','1','0'),
             Year4 = c('1','1','1','0','1','1'),
             Year5 = c('0','0','1','1','1','1'),
             Year6 = c('1','0','0','0','0','1'))

df
      group Year1 Year2 Year3 Year4 Year5 Year6
1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1
2     2     0     1     1     1     0     0
3     3     0     1     0     1     1     0
4     4     0     0     0     0     1     0
5     5     0     1     1     1     1     0
6     6     0     1     0     1     1     1
result <- data.frame(group=c(1:6), value = c(4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3))

result
  group value
1     1     4
2     2     3
3     3     2
4     4     1
5     5     4
6     6     3


A tidyverse solution without custom functions:
library(tidyverse)
# ----------------

df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Year")) %>% 
  mutate(id = consecutive_id(group, value)) %>% 
  add_count(group, id) %>% 
  filter(value == 1) %>% 
  summarise(.by = c(group), value = max(n))

Output:
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  group value
  <int> <int>
1     1     4
2     2     3
3     3     2
4     4     1
5     5     4
6     6     3

You can get values from both 1 and 0 if you want:
df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Year")) %>% 
  mutate(id = consecutive_id(group, value)) %>% 
  add_count(group, id) %>% 
  summarise(.by = c(group, value), n_value = max(n)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n_value, names_prefix = "val_")

# Output for both values 
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  group val_1 val_0
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     4     1
2     2     3     2
3     3     2     1
4     4     1     4
5     5     4     1
6     6     3     1

Or, with purrr::map_int and rle:
df$value <- map_int(
  df$group,
  \(x) max( rle(df[x, -1])$lengths[ rle(df[x, -1])$values == 1 ] ))

# Output
> df[, c("group", "value")]
  group value
1     1     4
2     2     3
3     3     2
4     4     1
5     5     4
6     6     3


We can write a function that will return the  maximum of row cumulative sums for each group.
get_max_length <- function(x) {
  rl <- rle(x)
  max(rl$lengths[rl$values == 1])
}

Now we can apply this function for each row.
In base R, using apply
cbind(df[1], value = apply(df[-1], 1, get_max_length))

#  group value
#1     1     4
#2     2     3
#3     3     2
#4     4     1
#5     5     4
#6     6     3

Or with dplyr rowwise :
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  transmute(group, 
            value = get_max_length(c_across(starts_with("Year")))) %>%
  ungroup()

